# Electron/Vite Cannot find modules after build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite, electron-builder

im facing a few problems after i built the project.
the error im facing: cannot find module newMessageHandler, axios, crypto
i tried using path.join(__dirname, 'events/newMessage.js'); but then i get error newMessage/axios/crypto is not a function
full code: https://github.com/DaYroXy/cryptwohale-desktop
of course i did install the dependencies 'npm i axios crypto etc...'

```
    const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
    const path = require('path');
    const newMessageHandler = require('./events/newMessage.js');
    const axios = require('axios')
    const crypto = require('crypto')
    const isDev = !app.isPackaged;
```

viteConfig

```
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
      build: {
        outDir: 'dist',
      },
      base: './', // Set base to './'
    });
```

*not really sure how to include events/* to the build as well as the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

[Cause]:

Vite imports Rollup when building, and Rollup actually bundles your code. By default, Rollup doesn't support CommonJS modules. So, `require('./events/newMessage.js')` doesn't work.

[Solution]:

There are two solutions.

1. Rewrite all the CommonJS modules to ES modules
2. Add `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` to `viteConfig`

The former solution is to replace `module.exports` with `export` and replace `require` with `import`. The latter is as follows.

```js
import { commonjs } from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), commonjs()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
  },
  base: './', // Set base to './'
});
```

With `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`, the mixed CommonJS and ES modules work.